# Why does the debugger say 'j' is lower than 'i'?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hi I just started using leetcode to improve my understanding of python. The first problem is a two sum algorithm which i viewed the solution for straight away and then I used my understanding to write a program that performs the same algorithm based on user input. My code works but when I debugged it to help myself understand the code more I noticed that 'j' is equal to 0 when 'i' is equal to 1 even though 'j' is supposed to be 'i' + 1. Any help understanding why is appreciated. Thanks!

```py
def main():
     target = int(input(" Target Number: "))
     nums = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
     print(two_sum(target, nums))


def two_sum(target, nums):
     for i in nums:
         for j in range(i + 1):
             if i == (target - j):
                 return i, j


if __name__ == "__main__":
     main()
```

Comment: Could you clarify what you think `for j in range(i + 1)` is doing?

Comment: `j` is not simply `i+1`. It is loop variable that has the values from `0` to `i + 1`, which you defined by using `range(i+1)`. At this point, your best action is to stop and learn some basic debugging skills. Just stepping through your code should answer many of your questions. P.S. I wouldn't recommend viewing answers at leetcode as a way to learn python. The point of leetcode is to practice writing algorithms, not to learn basic python programming.

Comment: _even though 'j' is supposed to be 'i' + 1_ What?  No it's not.  Please explain why you think that.

Comment: Sorry I had completely ignored the 'range' in the second for loop. Totally blanked and thought the second for loop was me setting 'j' to "'i' + 1"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using a nested for loop.
For each iteration of the `i` loop you will iterate i + 1 times in the j loop.
Each i loop iteration will have a new j loop iteration.
so when i=1 you will have 2 j loop iterations j = 0, j = 1
when i=2 you will have 3 j loop iterations j=0, j=1 ,j =2
and so on..

Comment: Thank you that makes total sense cant believe it didn't realize!